# Using a transformer type to map the value of each key into another type

Tags: typescript

With my first type as

```
type First = {
  a: string,
  b: number
}
```

Open to changes on how the `Dictionary` is implemented. A dictionary type could be as follows

```
type Dictionary = {
  string: { "stringValue": string },
  number: { "numberValue": number }
}
```

How do I make it so that I can create some `Transform<T>` that I can pass the `First` type through so that it will come out as

```
type Second = {
  a: { "stringValue": string },
  b: { "numberValue": number }
}
```

Given I can't read `typeof T` I can't figure out how I'd do an indexed access on the `Dictionary`. I can do a more manual way of a chain of conditional types, but seems very inelegant

```
type Dictionary<T> = T extends string ? { "stringValue": string } : { "numberValue": number }
type Second = {[Property in keyof First]: FieldValueOf<First[Property]>}
```

Comment: That `Dictionary` type isn't too helpful by itself, since `string` and `number` are just *keys* and there's no relation to the `string` and `number` *types*.  If you change `Dictionary` to something more useful, you can write a transformer like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wO8qzN).  If you need to keep `Dictionary` you'll find yourself writing silly helper types like `{string: string, number: number, boolean: boolean}`.  Let me know if the code I linked meets your needs. If so I can write up an answer; if not, please [edit] the question to show/describe failing use cases.

Comment: Yep your code example works - Extract and array is very clever indeed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need something *like* your `Dictionary` type, but the fact that they keys are named `"string"` and `"number"` has nothing to do with the *types* `string` or `number`, so it won't help the compiler transform `string` types into `{stringValue: string}`, without yet another mapping from `"string"` to `string`.  Instead, let's dispense with key names entirely. Like this:

```
type Mapping =
    [string, { "stringValue": string }] |
    [number, { "numberValue": number }]
```

Here `Mapping` is a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of 2-[tuples](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) where the first element in the tuple is the "from" type, and the second element is the "to" type.  You could represent this mapping in other ways (e.g., `{from: From, to: To}` instead of `[From, To]`) but this is good enough for your purposes.

Then, to map all the properties of a type `T` with `Mapping`, you can write this:

```
type UseMapping<T> = { [K in keyof T]: Extract<Mapping, [T[K], any]>[1] };
```

Here we use [the `Extract<T, U>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union) to find the member(s) of `Mapping` whose "from" type is compatible with the property type `T[K]`, and then from that we extract its "to" type (by [indexing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) into  it with the key `1`).  Let's see if it works:

```
type Second = UseMapping<First>;

/* type Second = {
    a: {
        stringValue: string;
    };
    b: {
        numberValue: number;
    };
} */
```

Looks good!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYglgJwM7CgXigbwFBT1AQwC4oUE4A7AcwBpd8AjEigVwFsGIFsBfbbUJCgBZAmDCUq6engDaZSTSxQARAuoA1AgBsWEFSXVSeAXSgAfGVFmsOXJZlW3OCLbv3N2LqKf6DoAKpIEKLikgA8ACoAfOjKsgDSUJRQANYQIAD2AGZQkSYkAKIAHsAIBADGwOGhEtRKspGJJkoEFCAm0bIAjGY8ANx+4NAAyhAVmRQAJnFBIWJ1VOHwyMDRg9gA9ABUUP5QYxPTcTj4hCSnZ-hGbnqGZZKDZwNWTFhWZ85ctxCedghPfAvHhQbabIA)

Comment: May be an adjacent question - this kind of mapping will not work if a type is defined as a literal type `'someString'` instead of a generic type `string`. How might I address that as well? Thanks again

Comment: I could make it work using `Extract<Mapping, [T[K] extends string ? string : T[K], any]>[1]` but that is very string specific, and loses the string literal upon conversion. Wondering if there's a more proper / general way to do it?

Comment: Yeah, this sort of thing is kind of what I was getting at when I asked for you to call out unmet use cases in your original question.  I can imagine fixing it so that `"foo"` will map to `{stringValue: string}` and still maybe have it in scope, but the part where you presumably want `{stringValue: "foo"}` is definitely out of scope.  Either way you might want to ask a new question given that at this point you'd be relying on my getting around to writing code for comments on an already-answered question on a weekend... you might have better luck getting eyes on it with a new one.

Comment: [Mapping `"foo"` to `{stringValue: string}` solution](https://tsplay.dev/w11gyw), and possibly [mapping `"foo"` to `{stringValue: "foo"}` solution](https://tsplay.dev/WK8Eyw) (depending on whether it's okay to assume that we just use the same value type as the original; frankly you'd need to spell out exactly what you want to see here because it's not obvious.)  Anyway I'm not inclined to modify this answer so I do recommend opening a new one if you have further questions.  Good luck!